# Running Impala on Mesos

Tags: hadoop, impala, mesos, mesosphere

Is it possible to run Impala on Mesos?

Has anyone tried this before?

I know there is [Llama](http://cloudera.github.io/llama/) for running Impala on YARN. Is there something similar with Mesos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't heard of anybody running Impala on Mesos, although it shouldn't be too hard to run it on Marathon or build a custom framework for it.

You could also run Impala on Llama on YARN on [Myriad](https://github.com/mesos/myriad) on Mesos, but that might be too many layers for you.

Comment: I believe MapR is experimenting with running Drill on Mesos, so Impala on Mesos should be similar.